# How to search and parse arbitrarily long JSON files in Rust?

Tags: json, rust

So a friend and I are making our own package manager in Rust and we need to parse JSON for it. We found [Rust Programming Tutorial #42 - Parsing JSON](https://youtu.be/hIi_UlyIPMg) and it shows us the basics on how to do so, but in our situation we're parsing files that can be as small as 1 entry to as big as 1000 (or more!). Here's the format of the JSON we need to parse:

```
[
    {
    "Name": "libexample",
    "Version": "5.0.0",
    "Depends": "dependency1, dependency2, dependency3",
    "Maintainer": "example@example.com",
    "Author": "person@author.com",
    "Homepage": "www.homepage.com",
    "Depiction": "package.depiction.com/file.json",
    "Description": "This  package contains an example!",
    "State": "Stable",
    "Provides": "Example",
    "Replaces": "Free space on your hard drive",
    "OS": "darwin, linux",
    "Architecture": "amd64"
    },
    {
    "Name": "libexample",
    "Version": "6.0.0",
    "Depends": "dependency1, dependency2, dependency3",
    "Maintainer": "example@example.com",
    "Author": "person@author.com",
    "Homepage": "www.homepage.com",
    "Depiction": "package.depiction.com/file.json",
    "Description": "This  package contains an example!",
    "State": "Beta",
    "Provides": "Example",
    "Replaces": "Free space on your hard drive",
    "OS": "darwin, linux",
    "Architecture": "amd64"
    },
    {
    "Name": "libexample",
    "Version": "7.0.0",
    "Depends": "dependency1, dependency2, dependency3",
    "Maintainer": "example@example.com",
    "Author": "person@author.com",
    "Homepage": "www.homepage.com",
    "Depiction": "package.depiction.com/file.json",
    "Description": "This  package contains an example!",
    "State": "Alpha",
    "Provides": "Example",
    "Replaces": "Free space on your hard drive",
    "OS": "darwin, linux",
    "Architecture": "amd64"
    },
    {
    "Name": "libanotherexample",
    "Version": "3.8.2",
    "Depends": "dependency1, dependency2, dependency3",
    "Maintainer": "example@example.com",
    "Author": "person@author.com",
    "Homepage": "www.homepage.com",
    "Depiction": "package.depiction.com/file.json",
    "Description": "This  package contains an example!",
    "State": "Stable",
    "Provides": "Another example",
    "Replaces": "Free space on your hard drive",
    "OS": "darwin, linux",
    "Architecture": "amd64"
    }
]
```

Our issue is we have no idea how to parse files that can be arbitrarily long and we have no idea how to search them. For example, if someone looks up a package name, how do we search through the entire file to match it with one of the name entries and then display the rest of that package's info?

Comment: Not an answer per se, but some thoughts: Normally you would not search through a JSON file directly, but read it into an internal data structure which is designed to make your algorithms (searching, updating, deleting, maybe sorting?) simple and fast. If your files are very long (probably many GB), reading the file all into memory at once may be an issue, in which case you may want to look into using a streaming parser. I think serde_json supports streaming, at least the existence of [`from_reader`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/de/fn.from_reader.html) suggests so.

Comment: @trentcl Yeah I meant arbitrarily long, also if loading it into memory all at once is an issue would storing it in a database (that rebuilds itself everytime it checks the json) and grabbing the info from there be a better option? If so then all I'd probably need to know is how I'd go about creating a database in Rust. If a database isn't a good option (Rust doesn't seem like it's there yet but I didn't research it extensively) then what else could I do? Would having a tuple of structs containing all the info by iterating over the file work? If not then what other options do I have?

Comment: Rust, actually cargo , has a local database. When you have a new cargo installation and you do `cargo build` for the first time, it `updates index` for couple of seconds. This is done only once, AFAIK, for whole installation and not per project. I'm not a rust expert, but it might be easier to get the basics in an "easier language" ,than port it to rust.

Comment: An existing database library is a fine option. I don't know what ones exist or are good for Rust, and that would be off-topic for this site anyway.  As for other options -- you have a lot! You need to design your data structures so that what tasks you want to do most are the fastest. Your data has more structure than the simple JSON file; for example, `State` is probably one of a fixed set of keys, `OS` may contain several keys from a fixed set, and `Depends` contains relationships to other members of the data set. You can exploit those structures to improve performance and reduce bloat.

Comment: Dependency graphs are typically [DAGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). You'll probably want to implement some graph traversal algorithms (topological sort, for instance, would tell you in what order to install dependencies), so you'd want to take that into account. You'll probably want to search by name. It's up to you to define the requirements. Architecture questions *are* on topic here, but it's a fine line to walk; I'd say you should have a design in mind, and explain why you think there's something wrong with it, rather than ask SO to make one for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
    extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_derive;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::str;
use serde_derive::Serialize;
use serde_derive::Deserialize;
#[derive(Serialize ,Deserialize)]
struct Person{
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    age: i64,
    }
    impl Person{
        fn show(&self){
            println!("First_Name:{}   Last_Name:{}   Age:{}",self.first_name,self.last_name,self.age);
        }
    }

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("text.json").unwrap();
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut data).unwrap();
  let s = match str::from_utf8(&data) {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
};
let values: Vec<_> = s.split("},").collect();
   let  mut i=0;
    while i<values.len(){
        let mut str1=values[i].to_string();
        if i==0{
             str1 = str1.replace("[", "");
            str1=str1+"}";
        }
        else if i==values.len()-1{
             str1 = str1.replace("]", "");
        }
        else{
            str1=str1.to_string()+"}";

        }
      let res=serde_json::from_str(&str1);
      if res.is_ok(){

         let p:Person=res.unwrap();
         p.show();
         }else{
        println!("Sorry ! we could not pass json");
     }
            i=i+1;

 } 
}




























/*fn main(){
    let mut file = File::open("text.json").unwrap();
    let  data = String::new();
    file.read_to_end(data).unwrap();
    let res=serde_json::from_str(&data);
    if res.is_ok(){
        let p:Person=res.unwrap();
        println!("{}",p.first_name);
        println!("{}",p.age);
    }
    else{
        println!("cannot pass the value");
    }

//     for i in data.iter(){
//     println!("{}",i);
// }
/*let s = match str::from_utf8(&data) {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
};*/
//println!("result: {}", s);


/*let str1=String::from(s);*/
//println!("result: {}", str1);



//let  main_vec= str1.lines().map(|s| s.trim().split('}').map(String::from).collect::<Vec<String>>()).collect::<Vec<Vec<String>>>();

/*for item in (main_vec).iter(){
    println!("{:?}",item);
    let str24:String=item;
    let res=serde_json::from_str(str24);
    if res.is_ok(){
        let p:Person=res.unwrap();
        println!("{}",p.first_name);
        println!("{}",p.age);
    }
    else{
        println!("cannot pass the value");
    }*/

    /*let strings = s.split("},");
    println!("{}",strings);
    for x in strings {
        //println!("{}", x);
        let res=serde_json::from_str(x);
    if res.is_ok(){
        let p:Person=res.unwrap();
         println!("{}",p.first_name);
        println!("{}",p.age);
        println!("-----------------------");
    }
    else{
        println!("cannot pass the value");
    }*/
      }*/
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before posting an answer.